# How to transform SELECT output column to arbitrary value based on this column?

Tags: sql, postgresql

For now I have following query:

```
SELECT "type" AS "modifiedType"
FROM "Table" 
WHERE "type" = 'type1' OR "type" = 'type2'
```

What I want is to return `modifiedType` like this:

```
if "type" = 'type1' then 'modifiedType1'
else if "type" = 'type2' then 'modifiedType2'
```

So I just want to modify column value with another value based on original column value.
Type column in `ENUM` not string.

I am using Postgres 9.3 (or 9.4?).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a `CASE` statement:

```
select type,
       case
         when type = 'type1' then 'modifiedType1'
         when type = 'type2' then 'modifiedType2'
         else type
       end as modifiedType
from the_table
WHERE type in ('type1', 'type2')
```

<sup>Btw: `type` is not a good name for a column</sup>

Answer (score 2):

A [**simple `CASE`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-CASE#) is more efficient with multiple alternatives for a single condition:

```
SELECT CASE type
          WHEN 'type1' THEN 'modifiedType1'
          WHEN 'type2' THEN 'modifiedType2'
          ELSE type
       END AS modified_type
FROM   tbl;
```

BTW, for a number of alternatives, it's shorter to write your `WHERE` clause like this:

```
WHERE type IN ('type1', 'type2', 'type3', ...)
```

Or even

```
WHERE type = ANY('{type1, type2, type3, ...}')
```

All variants are translated to the *same* `OR` list internally.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use case

```
SELECT
CASE
    WHEN "type" = 'type1'
    THEN 'modifiedType1'
    ELSE 'modifiedType2'
END AS "modifiedType"
FROM "Table"
```